# How can the variable of integration be a fraction?

Tags: integration

I'm having trouble understanding what this means:

$$-\int_0^t\ V_{in} \frac{dt}{RC} = V_{out}$$

How can you divide dt by RC?

Comment: One reason to write it this way is that $(t/RC)$ is dimensionless, which makes it somewhat easier to read the equation as a relationship between one voltage and another.

Answer (score 2):

$RC$ is just a constant, so you could just as well write your integral as 
$$-\int_0^t\ V_{in} \frac{dt}{RC} = -\frac 1{RC}\int_0^t\ V_{in}\ dt=V_{out}$$
In some cases you will do a $u$ substitution with $u=\frac t{RC}, du=\frac {dt}{RC}$